# How to slice time series in Pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

I've got a time series in which customers spend cash of certain value on a certain day. I've been asked to find out month-by-month how many unique customers there had been between the months between January 2018 and December 2018 and the proceeding 12 month period.

I'm struggling to work out how to use the `rolling()` function to set a 12-month window in order to calculate this number. What can I try?

```
date        value customers
2018-01-01  5.0   a
2018-01-01  10.0  a
2018-01-02  2.0   c
2018-01-04  10.0  b
2018-01-06  20.0  a
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need `groupby` on the period of index. I added a few more rows in the sample for different months and years

Sample `df`

```
            value customers
date
2018-01-01    5.0         a
2018-01-01   10.0         a
2018-01-02    2.0         c
2018-01-04   10.0         b
2018-01-06   20.0         a
2018-02-12    5.0         a
2018-02-12    2.0         c
2018-02-14   10.0         b
2018-02-16   20.0         a
2019-01-01    5.0         a
2019-01-01   10.0         a
2019-01-02    2.0         c
2019-01-06   20.0         a
2019-02-12    5.0         a
2019-02-12    2.0         c
2019-02-14   10.0         b
2018-02-16   20.0         a

df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).customers.nunique()

Out[281]:
date
2018-01    3
2018-02    3
2019-01    2
2019-02    3
Freq: M, Name: customers, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M'))['customers'].nunique()
```